# How many displays are supported by Ubuntu?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a 5 monitor setup at work and would like to go to Ubuntu, but only if I can get all of my displays to work.  How many monitors can Ubuntu support at one time??

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically as many as you have, but practically you could face problems...

I had problems with a PC with one ATI and one NVidia graphics card for 4 screens.

With two NVidia graphics cards I got it to work with Twinview using the proprietary driver. With ATI only configuration this should work as well, however this is not named TwinView. But I did never have two ATI graphics cards - thus untested.

About other graphics card vendors I have no information.

You should add some information especially on your Graphics hardware and Mainboard Chipset.

You mentioned 5 Screens - 2 cards with 2 screens each and one connected to an onboard graphics card? This might as well cause problems depending on which onboard solution it is.

Comment: I have two Radeon HD 5xxx series cards.  The chipset is Intel based.  My processor is a i7.  If I could get 4 monitors working that would be fantastic.

Comment: At least the four screens should work! The onboard intel graphics might not work. I suggest to boot into a Live environment, install the fglrx driver in this environment and test it that way.

Answer (score 0):

With latest montherboards & processor technology, it has become possible to use as many displays as you can.